# How to get the CLI parameter from bash?

Tags: bash

```
test.sh parameter
```

in `test.sh`, how can I get the parameter ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's a single parameter you use `$1` (and `$2` and so on, `$0` is the script name). Then, to get ALL parameters you use `$@`

Answer (score 4):

By accessing `$0` through `$9` (`$0` being the script name). Alternatively, `$*` returns the list of *all* parameters.

If you want to access the parameters one after another, or if you want to access parameters beyond the 9th, you can `shift` the parameters:

```
echo $1
shift
echo $1
```

When called like this:

```
./script.sh foo bar
```

will produce:

```
foo
bar
```

Comment: just curious, how to get the 10th parameter ?

Comment: @user198729: Uh … doesn’t my answer already explain that? You `shift` the parameters.

Comment: @user198729: this *is* a general solution. If you wanted to get the 100th parameter, you could `shift` 99 times and have the parameter in `$1`.

Comment: `${10}` seems to work, though I'm not sure about compatibility with other shells...

Answer (score 1):

Each argument is accessed by $NUM where NUM is the number of argument you wish to access. $0 is a special argument indicating the name of the script. $# returns the number of arguments.

```
test.sh alpha beta gamma
echo $0
echo $1
echo $2
echo $3
echo $#
```

Will give

```
test.sh
alpha
beta
gamma
3
```

[See here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash2.html)

Answer (score 0):

echo "$@"; prints all parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `shift` to "shift" through parameters.  `$1` contains the first parameter.  If you call `shift` then the second parameter will be "shifted" into `$1`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

At least in Bash, you can do either of these to access any parameter, including 10 and beyond:

```
echo "${10}"
echo "${@:10:1}"
```

To iterate over all the parameters:

```
for arg
do
    echo "$arg"
done
```

That form implies `for arg in "$@"`